# apt-get having dependency problems

Tags: apt, kernel

I noticed the issue when I tried to upgrade Python, but it seems to be a problem for all `apt-get` commands.

When I do `uname -a` I get

```
Linux sarah-ThinkPad-X220 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But when I try to run any `apt-get` command, I get errors saying related to linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic.

Here are all the error messages I get when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade python`:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic (3.13.0-63.103) ... Internal
Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic) dpkg:
error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic:
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic depends on
linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic; however:   Package
linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic; however:
Package linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic is not configured yet.
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic;
however:   Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic is not
configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problemsNo
apport report written because the error message indicates its a
followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a
followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
prevent configuration of linux-generic:  
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.63.71); however:   
Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
while processing:  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic  linux-image-generic
linux-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get similar errors with any `apt-get` command. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.
~

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17627/upgrading-to-python-3-2)

Comment: @Ravan I'm trying to upgrade python 2 (rather than install python3). I have both   Python 2 (python) and Python 3 (python3) and both are out of date. But I can't update either because of the problem above. I may be wrong, but I think this is not a problem with python but a problem with my kernal versions (or something else.) The problem seems broader than Python.

Comment: what is output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't actually look like I'm getting any errors on that one. It lists several packages and then prints `Reading packages lists... Done`

Comment: I can give you the whole output if you think that would help.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P linux-image-generic `and `sudo dpkg -P linux-generic` use these two commands!@Sarah

Comment: @Ravan That got rid of some of the errors, but not all of them. mchid's answer took care of the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try running the following commands:

```
cd ~/
mkdir aptget;cd aptget
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.103_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.103_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
cd ..
rm -R aptget
```

if it still complains, run the  following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! And change you could point me to any resources that could explain how this works?

Comment: @SarahO IDK, something was screwed up so I located the base dependency of linux-image-generic. I figured if you install that manually, it would fix things because the error said that it wasn't configured. First, make a temp. directory named "aptget" change to that directory, download the deb from security.ubuntu.com using wget, manually install using dpkg. Clean apt-get cache, update apt-get list, perform all upgrades, change back to home directory and finally, delete the temp directory. *Don't make a habbit of doing things this way.* It's not normal and should only be done as a last resort.